# Inline C# in <noscript> tags

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, noscript

I need to use the  tag in ASP.NET in order to call a C# method from the code behind class, but it seems to be calling it irrespective of whether JavaScript is enabled or disabled. Other text inside the tags works as expected.

Below is the code I am using, is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks

```
<noscript>
  other text here
  <% DisableTextBox("textBoxId"); %>
</noscript>
```

**Solution**
TextBox was disabled server-side, and enabled client-side using the following JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$("#txtTotalQuantScore").prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: The server-side won't know whether the client-side has javascript enabled before its been sent to the client..

Comment: If the client doesn't have scripting enabled, most of the .NET framework client-side functionality is not going to work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ASP.NET view engine knows nothing about the `noscript` tag you've included.

All server side code will be executed by the server and the result written to the HTML page. The `noscript` tag can not be used as a C# if statement.

If you want to disable something when Javascript isn't available you can do so client side.

One way would be to set the element in question to hidden in your CSS and then use Javascript to unhide it.

Answer (score 5):

As [@Jamie Dixon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860690/370103) has described, what you are trying to do is not possible.

Looking at your method name, it appears you are trying to disable a textbox if the browser doesn't support javascript.

Therefore I would recommend always disabling this textbox on the server-side, and enabling it with javascript on the client-side.

This way, only browsers supporting javascript will have the textbox enabled.

Comment: I enabled using JavaScript in the end, will put the code in the first post

Answer (score 1):

I would add you can detect server-side that a browser *supports* scripting, but there's no easy way to tell whether or not the user has *enabled* scripting.

You can resort to a trick like setting a value in a hidden field through a script (0 for no scripting, 1 for enabled, for example), but this isn't always reliable.